# PhpStorm PHPDocs document static facade class type to enable autocomplete

Tags: php, phpstorm, alias, static-methods, phpdoc

I create alias for static class using [class_alias](http://php.net/manual/function.class-alias.php) function:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Class A
 */
class A {
   static function doSomething() {
       print 42;
   }
}
// create alias, now calling B:: is the same like A::
class_alias('A', 'B');

// here autocomplete is not working
B::doSomething();
```

Everything work ok, except autocomplete is not working when I type `B::` and press <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd>.

Does PHPDoc or PhpStorm has some magic to help autocomplete to tell type of alias class to enable autocomplete, something as:

```
<?php
// /** @alias <full_name_of_original_class> <alias_name> */
/** @alias A B */
B::doSomething();
```

Comment: 1) PHPDoc has no `@alias` or similar tag 2) Same with PhpStorm 3) One day PhpStorm may support `class_alias()` -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11936 4) The only option I can offer you is to create something like `class B extends A {}` in a separate file that will be used by IDE only.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I've understood current situation. If you make an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Current PHPDoc (and [PSR-5](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md)) has no `@alias` or similar tag
2. Same with PhpStorm
3. One day PhpStorm may support `class_alias()`. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11936 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.
4. The only option I can offer you is to create something like `class B extends A {}` in a separate file that will be used by IDE only. BTW -- that's how Laravel's facades are supported (a way to tell IDE what those classes can do/what methods they have etc).